# Sending an XML file to a seperate application; JSP or Servlet? JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I have been researching into what type of Java web application I will need to create to carry out this use case activity:

> 1. Oracle CRM sends http request with GET variables
> 2. System uses GET variables in Oracle SQL query
> 3. System sends back XML file with SQL results to CRM via HTTP.

From what I have read so far there is two variations of JAVA that are web applications; those are JSP and Servlet.

Assuming I am not using any frameworks like Spring. What is the best way to implement this as a JSP application or Servlet.

Or is there other Java alternatives.

FYI: I am not a JAVA programmer, this is an introductory (in the deep end of the pool) project.

Thanks

Comment: If you are not a Java Programmer then it would be hard for you to use JSP and Servlets. You need to first have a clear understanding of the basics before jumping to create a web application. For the difference between JSP and Servlet, JSP is used for presenting the Data on web while Servlet is used for handling the BusinessLogic. Read about MVC Design Pattern on web to get a clear understanding.

Comment: @Arham ; I have used MVC in PHP (CodeIgniter/CakePHP) I am comfortable with that concept. But I am guessing from what you are saying I will need to use both JSP and Servlets for my application?

Comment: I.e. A servlet to handle the query, extraction and a JSP to send the XML?

Comment: Ask yourself just 2 questions, do you want to display some data on web that is returned from the server - Then you need a JSP. Do you want to apply some business logic on the server side to generate data, I guess yes as you want to query the database - then you need a Servlet.

Comment: @Arham ; when you mean display some data on the web are you meaning as a web page. Because I do not wan't to do that. I want to send an XML over HTTP back to a seperate system that takes the XML data and and does its own logic and presentation. So is JSP only for websites then?

Comment: Yes, in your case you only need a Servlet. And yes JSP is only for presentation layer. Although you can have business logic in JSP too because JSP ultimately gets converted to a Servlet in the backend but that's a bad practice not to be followed.

Comment: @Arham Thanks, if you like you can post that as an answer and I will give you the points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your case you only need a Servlet. And yes JSP is only for presentation layer. Although you can have business logic in JSP too because JSP ultimately gets converted to a Servlet in the backend but that's a bad practice not to be followed. :)